# How to load *.babylon exported from blender using JavaScript/FileApi/XHR?

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylonjs

I'm pretty fine working with the **.babylon** file format.
Exporter which was developed for Blender 3D editor works perfectly and if to load the exported model using the next code:

```
// won't write the full code
// because it was fetched from the playground and it's very standard and works
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("", "fileName.babylon", engine, function (newScene) {
...
```

works well and WebGL renderer in browser shows my model.

But, what if I don't want to load models as static files which must be saved in public folder of HTTP-server *( IIS, Apache, lighttpd, nginx, etc.. )*.

For e.g. I wanna load a **.babylon** file from the user's side or to secure the access to **.babylon** files at my backend.

All right, let's watch the situation, if I provide some kind of **Uploader** (using File API from browser) in my web-application, from which user will be able to load 3D-models from their PC or  other devices.

I'm trying to load models like this way:

File uploading ( `change` event of input-file ) which works well:

```
    function handleFiles( event ) {
        var uploader = event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
        var files = uploader.files;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function( event ) {
            var data = JSON.parse( event.target.result );
            loadCustomMesh( data );
        };

        // passing only single mesh because of testing purpose
        reader.readAsText( files[ 0 ] );
    }
```

Handling geometry and adding to scene:

```
function loadCustomMesh( data ) {
    var mesh = new BABYLON.Mesh( Math.random().toString(), scene );
    mesh.setVerticesData( BABYLON.VertexBuffer.PositionKind, data.meshes[ 0 ].positions, true );
    mesh.setVerticesData( BABYLON.VertexBuffer.NormalKind, data.meshes[ 0 ].normals, true );
    mesh.setIndices( data.meshes[ 0 ].indices );

    mesh.position = new BABYLON.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    ...
```

**It works FINE! But!!! Without materials...**

I've found that multimaterial is here from the uploaded data:

[image]

But if to use the next code:

```
mesh.material = data.multiMaterials[ 0 ];
```

Which is valid exactly for this sample, it throws the next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.needAlphaBlending is not a function
```

And I don't even know what to do next, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved here:

http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/16846-how-to-load-babylon-exported-from-blender-using-javascriptfileapixhr/

```
function handleFiles( event ) {
    var uploader = event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var files = uploader.files;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function( event ) {
        var result = event.target.result;

        BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh(
            null,
            event.target.result,
            '',
            scene,
            function( newMeshes, particleSystems, skeletons ) {
                var mesh = newMeshes[ 0 ];
                mesh.position = new BABYLON.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
            }
        );
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL( files[ 0 ] );
}
```